# How to solve this task using classes, vectors and etc

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, constructor

So i started fresh programming in OOP C++, i have experience with previous in programming. Anyway we started with classes, objects and constructors. I understood it kinda, but still have problem with this specifically task. I need to make it with classes and vectors. So i need to make that, at end of program it prints out the result of average passed exams. When i wrote classes and added in class Student this attributes, program is showing errors for **Informatics** saying:

> name followed by `::` must be a class

I tried it many ways but still can't figure it out. Can you help me to solve it, not just `name followed by :: must be a class` but whole program. Code is below. `int main()` is original code which was given in task

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class School
{
public:

};

class Informatics {
public:


};


class Student
{
public:
    string name;
    string surname;
    int passed;
    Student(string _name, string _surname, int _passed) {
        name = _name;
        surname = _surname;
        passed = _passed;
    }
};


int main() {
    School::Informatics::Student Ante("Ante", "Antic", 10); // 10 passed exams..
    School::Informatics::Student Ivica("Ivica", "Ivic", 12); // 12 passed exams..
    cout << School::Informatics::Student::AveragePassedExams() << endl; // 11 = (10+12)/2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you cover namespaces in your lecture already? This exercise looks like it wants you to use them

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well, as the OP uses `using namespace std;` they probably have a rough comprehension about _namespaces_ :-P

Comment: this may help ... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator#C.2B.2B

Comment: `School::Informatics::Student` what are you trying to achieve with this? Why connect these when you define them as separate classes?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking you can think of `::` as specifying that one thing is declared inside another. By doing `School::Informatics::Student` the compiler is going to look for the `Student` that's declared within `Informatics` that's declared within `School`.

But the problem is with the code you've shown, those classes are not declared within each other in that way. They're separate. So if you want to instantiate a `Student`, then just do something like `Student Ante("Ante", "Antic", 10);`.

On the other hand, if your aim really is to have `Student` nested within other classes/namespaces, it's possible to do so in a way that would make `School::Informatics::Student` valid. But it's not clear if that's your intent.

Comment: And if what you are really aiming for is an inheritance hierarchy, stop. A Student is not a School, so modelling a Student as a School will only lead to pain down the line..